# WPF : Caching images for BitmapImage from internet

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, image, caching

The images I want to show in the WPF application do not change. So it would help greatly if I can use caching to display these images.

I have a user control that has an Image control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ucImage">
  <Grid>
    <Image Name="docImg">
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I download the image into a BitmapImage (hoping to use the system internet cache). I am setting the Source of the Image to the BitmapImage.

```
Public Class ucImage

Private WithEvents bi As BitmapImage

Private _URL As String
Public Property URL As String
    Get
        Return _URL
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _URL = value
        bi = New BitmapImage(New Uri(URL), New Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.CacheIfAvailable))
        If Not bi.IsDownloading Then SetControlProperties()
    End Set
End Property

Private Async Sub bi_DownloadCompleted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bi.DownloadCompleted
    bi.Freeze()
    SetControlProperties()
End Sub

Private Sub SetControlProperties()
    docImg.Source = bi
End Sub

Private Sub bi_DecodeFailed(sender As Object, e As ExceptionEventArgs) Handles bi.DecodeFailed
    Trace.WriteLine("Decode failed - " & _URL)
End Sub

Private Sub bi_DownloadFailed(sender As Object, e As ExceptionEventArgs) Handles bi.DownloadFailed
    Trace.WriteLine("Download failed - " & _URL)
End Sub

End Class
```

This works fine as long as the app is connected to the internet, but raises the DownloadFailed event when the device is offline - even when that same image was displayed in the app before it went offline.

Do I have to implement my own file caching or can I freeride on the Windows / .Net framework infrastructure?

Comment: In case there are not too many images, you may simply store them in a Dictionary, or an [ObjectCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.objectcache).

Comment: Thanks Clemens, this is an offline reader kind of an app. The app might be terminated when online and launched when offline. Have put in a quick and dirty file cache for now. Want to avoid the work of cleaning up the cache for stale files.